# way to allocate more than 1000 achievement points?

Tags: facebook, achievements

Is there a way to request or allocate more than 1000 achievement points for your application?

The issue here is that I am developing a game and plan to have regular content pack expansions.  Along with those expansions, I want to include new achievements relating to whatever new content is included.

My initial plan was to simply reduce the value for each achievement, say 1pt for easy, 3 for medium, 5 for difficult and just keep utilizing the 1000 point pool as slowly as I could.  Obviously, this wouldn't solve the problem, but it'd be a decent compromise.

However, after reading the description of how the achievements work at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/ I'd rather not hamstring my application by utilizing point values that will not be distributed.

So, does anyone know of a way to overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation I've read (which includes the URL you provided) you can not exceed 1000 points allocated to any given player. So there is no reason why you can't launch new content packs with new achievements, it's just that you won't be able to allocate any of them to any players (or won't get any distribution within Facebook if you do) for any players who have already achieved their lifetime maximum of 1000 points with your app. If you design your gameplay mechanics so that you essentially have to achieve every previous achievement to reach the latest one, then it means that eventually, additional content packs you publish won't be publishable to facebook via the Achievements API.

So, to your first question, no there is no way to request or allocate more than 1000 achievement points for your application for a given user.

To your second question, make sure you've read the achievements section of this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/growth/

Here they talk about how much distribution you get for the number of points you allocate to each achievement. If the goal is to maximize your distribution, then you need to design your game around achievements that put at least a 100 point value on your game's most notable achievements. If you choose 5 of these because you plan to have five content pack expansions, and you want your app to continue to push notifications for your players who have played all five, you need to consider allocating a maximum of 500 points to the other tiers of achievement distribution tiers.

So ultimately, this is a task that balances the achievements you have in the game with the amount of distribution you want to get in Facebook, and that each player in the game has a LTV associated with this API that once you hit 1000 represents little value to you to promote via the Achievements API beyond that point.

If you design your game such that achievements aren't linear, and if people can play the latest content packs without completing the previous ones, then newer players can publish new achievements that older players who have already achieved 1000 points worth won't be able to.

EDIT: Also consider this blog post, which indicates that Facebook seems to want to have all the achievements defined up-front to show the "you've accomplished 1 of n accomplishments so far" kind of progress:
http://devgotchas.grgventures.com/node/9

Comment: It's not '1000 to any given player' - it's '1000 across all possible achievements for that app'. Super short answer to the OP's question is 'no, the limit is 1000, use fewer points per achievement if you need more achievements'

Comment: I figured that was the answer, but I thought I'd ask anyway, in case someone more clever than I had thought of a way around the limitation.

Comment: Sorry to hijack your question but what happened when you have +82 achievement points one morning, and by the afternoon you only had 2!? Im still trying to understand SO even after reading their Help section on it.